# Save and resend Alamofire request

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, httprequest, alamofire

I am using Alamofire and I want to send a get request. If this fails, I want to retry it again after some other operations.

I save the request in a variable:

```
let myRequest = Alamofire.request("myurl", method: .get)
```

and in another function:

```
func retry(request:DataRequest) {
   request.responseSwiftyJSON { response in
      // ... code to handle the response ...
   }
}
```

In this way, I can call multiple times the retry function, passing the same object myRequest.

However, the request is sent correctly only the first time, then I think it is cached (or in some way the Alamofire object realizes that the response field of the request object is already valid) and the request is not sent again to the server.

To solve this problem, I tried to change a little bit the retry function in this way:

```
func retry2(request:DataRequest) {
   Alamofire.request(request.request!).responseSwiftyJSON { response in
      // ... code to handle the response ...
   }
}
```

This should initialize a new Alamofire request using only the URLRequest field of the saved request, but now the request is called twice every time! (I check it in my backend and I am sure this is caused by using this approach).

Is there any way to resend the original saved request? Does Alamofire have some way to initialize a new request from a saved one?

**Solution**

I ended up by doing something like @JonShier and @DuncanC suggested me:

```
struct APIRequest {

let url: URLConvertible
let method: HTTPMethod
let parameters: Parameters?
let encoding: ParameterEncoding
let headers: HTTPHeaders?

init(_ url:URLConvertible, method:HTTPMethod = .get, parameters:Parameters? = nil, encoding:ParameterEncoding =  URLEncoding.default, headers:HTTPHeaders? = nil) {
    self.url = url
    self.method = method
    self.parameters = parameters
    self.encoding = encoding
    self.headers = headers
}

func make() -> DataRequest {
    return Alamofire.request(url, method: method, parameters: parameters, encoding: encoding, headers: headers)
}

}
```

Comment: I believe that the request object that is generated can be considered an operation. You need to regenerate the request, each time you want to retry. Holding a regency to the request, from I believe, is intended to be cancelled for the most part. If you keep a unique reference to it, it also allows you to check if one already exists, and cancel it, before resending the same request

Comment: @AntonTheDev do you know if there is a way to create a new request starting from a completed one?

Comment: Try making the method func triggerRequest(for URL:String){} . Then in the failure block call it again :) But be sure to somehow track that your attempted it 3 times, cause you can have a runaway effect. Also you can trigger logic specific to timeouts, connectivity loss, etc, to not retry based on the error code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used AlamoFire much, and that minimal use was a couple of years ago.

Looking around in the AlamoFire code, it appears that the `request()` function returns a `DataRequest` object. Further, it looks like a `DataRequest` is a reference type that is meant to track a specific request to a server and it's responses.

It looks to make like once you create one, you use it until it completes or fails, and then discard it. They do not appear to be intended to be reused for subsequent requests of the same type.

To summarize:

**Question:** "How do I reuse AlamoFire DataRequest objects." 
**Answer:** "Don't do that."

Comment: So, I have to save all request params (like url, method, headers, params, ...) and recreate a new DataRequest object each time, right?

Comment: @keyblade95 You need to save whatever representation you feed to Alamofire. That could be separate variables, a single type that contains all of the relevant info, or the `URLRequest` you give to Alamofire. I recommend a type that conforms to Alamofire's `URLRequestConvertible` and stores all of the parameters required. That way you can persist it and send it to Alamofire whenever you need.

Comment: A struct of some sort seems like a natural choice. Put the URL, method, headers, and the like into a struct.  I'm at work now and don't have AlamoFire on my work machine, but an object that conforms to the URLRequestConvertible protocol sounds like a good choice, as suggested by Jon Shier in his comment.

Comment: @JonShier I ended up doing like you suggest me

Comment: @DuncanC I ended up doing like you suggest me